# Xamarin.Forms ListView not properly resizing (only on iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, listview, xamarin.forms

I'm using a ListView in Xamarin.Forms. I have a problem with the resizing of the rows. When I start my application on portrait mode, the width of the rows fill the screen (as intended), but when I rotate to landscape mode they become wider. So far so good, but when I switch back to portrait again the rows stays the width as they were on landscape mode. This behaviour is not seen on an Android application with exactly the same code.

I've only tested this on the iOS simulator so far. It has the same behaviour on the iPad and the iPhone simulator.

Have I encountered a bug?

Comment: Can you post some code to re-produce?